# Project created using cookiecutter-django not running

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django

Its been a few months that I am trying to learn Django. In the same process (and while reading "Two Scoops of Django 1.11"), I came across Cookiecutter Django. It has helped me learn a few important things to keep in mind while creating a project.

I tried to run the template provided by cookiecutter-django but failed. Here are the steps that I followed.

1. Create a virtual environment named **test** and activate it.

`mkvirtualenv test`

2. Installed **Cookiecutter**.

`pip install coockiecutter`

3. Installed **Cookiecutter Django**, The project name was set to "Test Project" and other defaults settings were chosen. I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.
   `cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django`
4. Create a database named "test_project" in PostgreSQL.
5. Run `python manage.py migrate`

The result was the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "dev" does not exist
```

I have also tried making a user named test_project_user and granting it all the privileges to test_project database. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you specified a database user that does not exist (or you left blank and it assumes your system user), in:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_project',
        'USER': 'HERE', # Set test_project_user here
        ...
    }
}
```